# Why need to keep the large strings created in the bottom of the stack in Lua string buffer

Tags: lua

I recently read section [11.6 String Buffers](https://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html) of Programming in Lua. The writer gave an algorithm that is similar to Tower of Hanoi to keep the large strings created in the bottom of the stack when reading a text file line by line.

Why would this approach need in the string buffer data structure? Is this some sort of hack to speed up the memory manipulation?

What I don't understand is why the author concatenates small strings into a large one?

For example, why not just use this as an `addString` function?

```lua
function addString (stack, s)
    table.insert(stack, s)    -- push 's' into the the stack
end
```

Comment: Did you read the first few paragraphs of the article you linked? It describes why naively appending strings may be slow.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I do understand that appending strings like ` buff = buff .. line .. "\n" ` will be slow. What I don't understand is why not just simply insert the string no matter the length into a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, why not just use this as an addString function?

Because you'd still need a way to concatenate all the strings you inserted. You'd probably use `table.concat` to do that, but the algorithm presented shows hows it can be done (in a reasonably performant way) without using the `table.concat` function. You can simply use `table.insert`, as you suggested, but the example is shown to describe what you'd do to improve the performance (even though the same algorithm is already implemented and available for you).

[updated to address the question in the comment on what's different]

Let's see what's different from the GC perspective.

```
local t = 0
function addString (stack, s)
  table.insert(stack, s)
  for i=#(stack)-1, 1, -1 do
    if string.len(stack[i]) > string.len(stack[i+1]) then
      break
    end
    print(#(stack[i+1]), #(stack[i]))
    t = t + #(stack[i+1]) + #(stack[i])
    stack[i] = stack[i] .. table.remove(stack)
  end
end

local s = {""}
local tbl = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
for _, line in ipairs(tbl) do
  addString(s, line)
end
while #s > 1 do
  local i = #s-1
  print(#(s[i+1]), #(s[i]))
  t = t + #(s[i+1]) + #(s[i])
  s[i] = s[i] .. table.remove(s)
end
print(t, s[1])

local s = ""
local t = 0
for _, line in ipairs(tbl) do
  print(#s, #line)
  t = t + #s + #line
  s = s .. line
end
print(t, s)
```

If we run both the suggested and naive algorithms, as shown above, we can see that the first algorithm reports 65 for the length of freed strings and 136 for the second algorithm. That's where the savings in the memory re-allocations are coming from (even though the number of operations is the same in both cases).

You can see it in the simplest possible case: 1, 1, 1, 1. The first algorithm will combine them as 1+1, 1+1 and then 2+2, with the results string as 4 and the freed (intermediate) strings as 1,1,1,1,2,2 for a total of 8.

The naive algorithm will do 1+1,2+1,3+1, with the same resulting string 4, but the freed strings as 1,1,1,1,2,3 for a total of 9.

The more strings are being concatenated, the larger the advantage is going to be.

Comment: Still don't understand why in this way the performance is improved. Using Tower of Hanoi like algorithm will sometime iterate over the previously added string and concatenate them into a new string (which will involve GC I guess).

Comment: Updated the answer to address.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and misleading address. My real confusion is that performance improved between the Tower-of-Hanoi-like algorithm and put all small strings into a table then concatenating the table into one at the end with `table.concat`.

Comment: I do understand the Tower-of-Hanoi-like algorithm is much better than the naive way `s = s .. line` .

Comment: The performance improved (between implementing ToH in Lua and table.concat in C) because while `table.concat` implements a version of brute force algorithm, it does it in a memory efficient way (doubling the buffer size when there is not enough space), which extends the buffer if possible instead of re-allocating it for every string addition. As far as I understand, this also happens outside of GC runs, which makes it perform even better comparing to the ToH implementation in Lua.